# Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in different method

Tags: android

```
new Thread(new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run() {
                        while ( statusStr==null)
                        {
                            progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                    }).start();
```

Friends,I have referred other question but I am still confused so please help me in solving this issue. I cannot keep statusStr as final coz its values are updating while the app is working so please give me a solution.

Comment: you need to give us more than this.

Comment: @JonTaylor
The statusStr value is the response I am getting from the app.. while it  is communicating with other resources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the variable globally so that you will not be forced to change it to final.

Comment: I have declared it as global variable,the error is also vanished, value of String statusStr is null(LOg shows ) but its not entering while loop.. Please help

Comment: Did you try adding that log inside run() before starting while loop and check?

Comment: new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
     public void run() {
      Log.e("","INSIDE RUN");
      while (statusStr.isEmpty())
      {
       Log.e("","HERE");
       progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
         progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
        }
       });
      }

     }
    }).start();

Comment: Why have you uses isEmpty() here. It does not mean your string is null. Did u check with statusStr==null itself for your while?

Comment: 0 down vote favorite
 

In my application I have an account activation form, which gets authenticated via Internet.IN the mean time (after the activate button is click)I wish to show some sort of UI to the user so that he knows that activation is in progress. Please can u share the code with me.

Comment: Change this Log.e("","INSIDE RUN"); to  Log.e("","INSIDE RUN "+statusStr); and see what it prints for the value of statusStr. If it prints null then we will see about some other method to achieve this.

Comment: the code is working now.. wrong condition check... but the progress bar is invisble..

Comment: progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressBar.setCancelable(true);
    progressBar.setMessage("Activation in progress");
    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    progressBar.show();

    //reset progress bar status
    progressBarStatus = 0;


followed by new Thread sniipet the 3 comment

Comment: Then try changing this progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); to progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14511/discussion-between-onkar-and-andro-selva)

Answer (score 0):

Either declare progressBar as final or declare it as a GlobalVariable.

Like declaring final variable do as follows:

```
final ProgressBar progressBar= ProgressBar.show(this, "title", "message");
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() {
                            while ( statusStr==null)
                            {
                                progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                        }
                        }).start();
```